# If statement with string issues

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

Here is my code (I'm editing a script used in Xsplit to parse html files, and I'm trying to set the final variable - responseEdited to "No active match." if the variable - responseEdited - contains the string 'winning'. However, the result of the code below appears to be null into that variable.

```
/*replace some text in the string*/
var responseEdited = responseCleaned.replace('</h3><h3>', 'vs. ');

/*this is the problem area*/
/*if it contains "winning", change to no active match*/
if(responseEdited.contains("winning"))
   {
     responseEdited = "No active match.";
   }
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that you should not be putting JavaScript code in a Java program.

Comment: It's a portion of the program that is designed to have editable Javascript (there is a built in editor) for custom parsing of html.

Comment: It's JavaScript code.  So please don't put the "java" tag on it.  You want JavaScript experts to be looking at your question, right?

Comment: It works if I don't have the if statement in.

Comment: Understood, tag changed, thank you.

Comment: I am not aware of a `contains` method on the JavaScript `String` type.

Comment: Sorry, I am including a portion of the code. The code behaves as intended if I do not have the if statement shown above included.

Comment: Use `responseEdited.indexOf("winning") > -1`

Comment: That must be it! This is my first attempt at JavaScript, my web searching must have lead me to Java code.

Comment: @Brandon - Apparently it was at one time.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains

Comment: @PM77-1 Strange, but cool!  I can call it just fine in Chrome, yet it's not in the spec.  I guess Mozilla standardized it.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work without changing it, just add the following polyfill to the top of your script. If the function exists in a particular browser's JavaScript engine, then this will be ignored, otherwise the function will be added to String's prototype.

## `String.prototype.contains()`

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function() {'use strict';
    return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
  };
}
```

This is the [MDN suggested polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill).